# Using dynamic data for my Axios BodyContent from a react form returns an error, but hardcoding the same values works

Tags: reactjs, axios, formik

I'm dealing with a really strange issue here.

In the code below you'll see 2 versions of `BodyContent`, one where the values are hardcoded
and the other where they dynamic values that are passed through a `Formik` form. The former works and the latter returns a 500 internal error.

```
export async function fetchAcuantData ( _bfn, _bln, _bsn, _bc, _bs, _bz, _bco) {
 /* var BodyContent= JSON.stringify({

    "bfn": "Namey",
    "bln": "McNameFace",
    "bsn": "1201 Horse St",
    "bc": "New York",
    "bs": "NY",
    "bz": "34343",
    "bco": "USA"
  });
*/
 var BodyContent= JSON.stringify({

   "bfn": _bfn,
   "bln": _bln,
   "bsn": _bsn,
   "bc": _bc,
   "bs": _bs,
   "bz": _bz,
   "bco":_bco
 });
  console.log (data)
  var config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost:4041/checkuser',
    headers: { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data : data
  };
  
  axios(config)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });      
}
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this passing the exact same data into the dynamic one? Also, what is `_man`?

Comment: @Scrapper142 I have done this. Regarding ```_man```, sorry, I was meant to remove it. I've updated my post.

Comment: Does `console.log(data)` print the same thing in both versions?